# Control LED using ESP8266 with Arduino

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

How I discover when this buttons was clicked?

```
webpage += "Click <a href=\"/H\">here</a> Ligar a led<br>";
webpage += "Click <a href=\"/L\">here</a> Desligar a led <br>";
```

On ESP without Arduino I can do it using "endsWith", but I don't know how to do it with Arduino and ESP.

Does the function "esp8266.find("H")" work?

Answer (score 0):

Please explain better your problem.

In Arduino-Esp8266 String have the endsWith.

Example:

```
String test = "AAAAAH";
if (test.endsWith("H")) {
    //...
}
```